# How can I insert this union all selects inside my procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm having problems with logic, to think how can I put this code inside a procedure, as a field.Tried with CTE but failed too.

```
 SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro,  tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,'2015-07-01')
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro in (2749,2751)
                AND R.cod_status in(7)
                and r.datahora_emissao >= convert(date,'2015-07-01')                                

                                            union all

 SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro , tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,'2015-07-01')
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro in (2749,2751)
                AND R.cod_status in(2,3)

                                          union all
 SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro , tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                    join tbFiles on tbfiles.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,'2015-07-01')
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro in (2749,2751)
                AND R.cod_status in(6)
                and tbfiles.file_assinado = 0
```

it will create something like this:

[image]

But, this is for a test purpose, because I was trying to create a temp table inside the procedure like this:

```
create table #temp ( cod_rep int, cod_perito_primeiro int, datahora_solicitacao datetime)
go
insert into #temp

 SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro,  tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,'2015-07-01')
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro in (2749,2751)
                AND R.cod_status in(7)
                and r.datahora_emissao >= convert(date,'2015-07-01')                                

                                            union all

 SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro , tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,'2015-07-01')
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro in (2749,2751)
                AND R.cod_status in(2,3)

                                          union all
 SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro , tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                    join tbFiles on tbfiles.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,'2015-07-01')
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro in (2749,2751)
                AND R.cod_status in(6)
                and tbfiles.file_assinado = 0

select min(datahora_solicitacao)  from #temp
    group by cod_perito_primeiro
drop table #temp
```

I'm having problems with 2 things:

One: This query will need to run with parameters ( because it's already inside a procedure). the real query needs to be this way:

```
(SELECT COUNT(distinct r.cod_rep) 
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,@data)
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro = cod_usuario
                AND R.cod_status in(7)
                and r.datahora_emissao >= convert(date,@data))                                

                                     union all

(SELECT COUNT(distinct r.cod_rep) 
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,@data)
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro = tbUsuarios.cod_usuario
                AND R.cod_status in(2,3)) 

                                    union all

(SELECT COUNT(distinct r.cod_rep) 
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                    join tbFiles on tbfiles.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,@data)
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro =cod_usuario
                AND R.cod_status in(6)
                and tbfiles.file_assinado = 0) as  'Casos_Pendente

s_Por_Perito',
```

So, How can I use this 3 union all, inside a procedure, as a single field? The purpose of this, is to select all data from these 3 selects, and grouping by `cod_rep`, get the minimum value ( `min(tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao)`)

I tried to create a procedure and call it inside this procedure, but failed.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: SIntax error. But I could manage to fix it. The answer is what I did:

Answer (score 0):

After some time thinking, this is what I did. probably not the best ( neither the faster ) solution. PLease I would be glad to learn a better way to do this.

```
Beggining of the procedure with a lot of selects as fields...
,

 (select min(datahora_solicitacao) from (

       SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro,  tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                    join tbUsuarios on tbUsuarios.cod_usuario=r.cod_perito_primeiro
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,@data)
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro = tbUsuarios.cod_usuario
                AND R.cod_status in(7)
                and r.datahora_emissao >= convert(date,@data)                                

                                            union all

 SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro , tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                    join tbUsuarios on tbUsuarios.cod_usuario=r.cod_perito_primeiro
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,@data)
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro = tbUsuarios.cod_usuario
                AND R.cod_status in(2,3)

                                          union all
 SELECT r.cod_rep,r.cod_perito_primeiro , tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao
                FROM tbReps as R
                    join tbSolicitacoes on tbSolicitacoes.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                    join tbFiles on tbfiles.cod_rep=r.cod_rep
                    join tbUsuarios on tbUsuarios.cod_usuario=r.cod_perito_primeiro
                WHERE
                convert(date,tbSolicitacoes.datahora_solicitacao) <= convert(date,@data)
                AND R.cod_perito_primeiro = tbUsuarios.cod_usuario
                AND R.cod_status in(6)
                and tbfiles.file_assinado = 0


       ) as teste
        where tbUsuarios.cod_usuario=teste.cod_perito_primeiro
           group by cod_perito_primeiro
           ) as 'Data_Caso_Mais_Antigo',
```